# Determine if the given set is a real linear space

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine if the given set is a real linear space under the usual operations.

- The set of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$
- The set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ that satisfy $f(0)=0$
- The set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ that satisfy $f(1)=1$

I have tried the following:

- Let $P$ the set of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$.

  Let $f,g \in P$. Then $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c, a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $g(x)=dx^2+ex+t, d,e,t \in \mathbb{R}$.

  Then $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)=(ax^2+bx+c)+(dx^2+ex+t)\\=(a+d)x^2+(b+e)x+(c+t) \in P$

  Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}, f \in P$. Then $(\lambda f)(x)=\lambda \cdot f(x)=\lambda(ax^2+bx+c)=(a\lambda)x^2+(b \lambda)x+(c \lambda) \in P$

So the set of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$ is a real linear space.

- We define $B=\{f \in C[0,1]: f(0)=0\}$.

  Let $f, g \in B, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $f+g \in C[0,1]$ and $(f+g)(0)=f(0)+g(0)=0$. Also, $(\lambda f)(x)=\lambda f(x) \in  C[0,1] $ and $(\lambda f)(0)=\lambda f(0)=0$.

  So the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ that satisfy $f(0)=0$ is a real linear space.
- Let $K=\{ f \in C[0,1]: f(1)=1\}$.

  Let $f,g \in K$. Then $(f+g) \in C[0,1]$. But $(f+g)(1)=f(1)+g(1)=2 \neq 1$.

  Thus the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ that satisfy $f(1)=1$ is not a real linear space.

Could you tell me if the above is right?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: @egreg Nice, thank you :)

Comment: Right, all is O.K.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct.

The verification for the polynomials can be done by saying

> the degree of the sum of two polynomials is at most equal to the degree of the summands; multiplying a polynomial by a scalar doesn't increase the degree

so that this proves the statement for any fixed degree.

Only a minor point for the third case: you should prove by providing an example, but taking $f$ and $g$ the constant function $1$, you're done. Anyway, it's pretty clear that there are continuous real functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f(1)=1$; if there weren't, the set would be empty and so not a vector space as well.

Comment: I see... If we would take two polynomials that belong in the set of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$, where would the coefficients belong to?

Comment: @evinda When you talk about polynomials, you are implicitly assuming where the coefficients are taken from; in your case they're probably the real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite correct.

(1) Firstly, you mean "the set of **real** polynomials". Secondly, a set of real **polynomials** does not contain any real numbers, so "$f,g \in P$" is right but "$(a+d)x^2+(b+e)x+(c+t) \in P$ is technically wrong. Instead, $f+g \in P$. Same for "$(aλ)x^2+(bλ)x+(cλ)$".

(3) "Let $f,g \in K$" is not right. Firstly notice that throughout you have used "let" in two incompatible ways, one for universal quantification and the other for instantiation of an existential quantification. This is the source of the error, and you should be clear on which one you mean at each point. To prove something is a vector space, you show that it satisfies all the axioms, which are all universally quantified. Thus if you want to prove that something is not a vector space, you have to show that some axiom is not satisfied, and that means to show its negation, which would be existentially quantified. So you need to construct an object that witnesses that negation. Until you do so, "Let $f,g \in K$" does not make sense.

Comment: So $x^2+1$ is not a polynomial?

Comment: @egreg: You have to be very precise about it. Most my textbooks and teachers were quite sloppy about this. Do you define a polynomial as a function from an initial segment of $\mathbb{N}$ to its coefficients? If so, then it is utterly wrong to write $f(1)$ when meaning the evaluation of polynomial $f$ on $1$. Or do you define a polynomial as a string of symbols, specifically a well-formed term? If so, then "$x^2+1$" (with the quotes!) as a string can be considered to be a polynomial in $x$, but $x^2+1$ is not.

Comment: @egreg: Or do you define a polynomial to be a certain type of function? If so, then $( x \mapsto x^2+1 )$ is a real polynomial (with "$x$" as a dummy variable), but $x^2+1$ is just a term (with "$x$" as a free variable).

Comment: @egreg: This may seem unnecessarily pedantic, but it won't be so funny when students get to more complicated objects such as meta-proofs and higher-order functions and no longer can have a firm understanding of what is what because they are not used to being careful with types.

Comment: Sorry, but $x^2+1$ is a polynomial when we agree that $x$ is an *indeterminate*. I would surely define a polynomial as an eventually zero sequence, then identify the constant polynomial with the real numbers and finally set $x=(0,1,0,\dotsc)$. This is well explained in all algebra books.

Comment: @user21820 Could you explain me further why $(a+d)x^2+(b+e)x+(c+t) \in P$ is technically wrong?

Comment: @evinda: What type of object is the expression before the $\in$? It is not a polynomial, but a value. You took polynomials $f,g$ from $P$. If $f$ is a polynomial, then $f(x)$ is not a polynomial, just as you yourself used "$f(0)$" to mean "the value of $f$ evaluated at $0$".

Comment: @egreg: If you specify $x$ as an indeterminate, then you can of course say that "$x^2+1$" is a polynomial, but one then has to be careful not to mix up indeterminates and free variables. You may know very well what it is, but I can assure you that many students don't.

Comment: @egreg: For example, in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ we have $(x+y)^p = x^p+y^p$ for any $x,y \in F$, but this does not trivially imply that $f(x)^p$ and $f(x^p)$ are the same polynomial for any polynomial $f$ over $F$ and indeterminate $x$. It only implies that they have equal evaluation on all elements $F$, but not necessarily the same coefficients. However, I've actually observed that many students will not notice this at all and hence think they have a proof of equality of the two polynomials due to the confusion between indeterminates and free variables.

Comment: @user21820 $x\in F$ is not an indeterminate.

Comment: @egreg: Exactly! As I said, many students mix them up! If you ask students to prove the fact I stated, many of them will give an incorrect proof because of this issue.

Comment: @user21820 It never happened to my students.

Comment: @egreg: That just means that either you are a good teacher or your students are good students. What I have observed is that few of my teachers succeeded in that, which may mean that either they are not very clear in their teaching or the students don't really know what they are doing or both.